# Angular js : How to access dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to get value of of $scope with a dynamic loop value.

```
<div ng-repeat="que in questions[$state.current.name]">

<text-control-dir data="que.QuestionData" default="{{que._attributename}}"></text-control-dir>

</div>
```

Here que._attributename I passed to pass dynamically. that will come from ng-loop.

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: here index _attributename is dynamic value that I am trying to access in scope.

Comment: create fiddle or plnkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
<text-control-dir data="que.QuestionData" default="{{que[_attributename]}}"></text-control-dir>
```

Below is an example explaining the above:

```
var obj = { name: 'Abcd'};
var varName = 'name';
console.log(obj[varName]) // this will return 'Abcd'
```

Comment: {{que[_attributename]}}  here you are trying to get same value from que object. I want value from a $scope object. assume like $scope.PC.

Comment: Either use controllerAs format or access PC to another variable and access as I mentioned.

Comment: updated pluker http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview as per you answer. But its gives error.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use $scope in the html. To access $scope.que._attributename from the controller, you just use it like this without the `$scope`

```
<text-control-dir data="que.QuestionData" default="{{que._attributename}}"></text-control-dir>
```

Comment: my question is different. assume que returned 'PC' and $scope.PC = 'str'. then how will I access dynamic value as per loop.

Comment: @Greatym.com `$scope` is available when you create a `ng-controller` so in the view you don't have to explicitly place the `$scope`. `que._attributename` will work. Better to post your controller too in the question.

Comment: question updated removed $scope. now I want to know how to get dynamic value. as you can see in code I am want to get value through loop from scope. my loop have index.